# Why do i get this runtime error when i instruct a turtles to set its heading towards a patch with a certain pcolor?

Tags: netlogo

I want to be make turtles set their heading towards one of the patches that have pcolor = grey  in a cone of 1 270 when they are on a patch with pcolor = 6. My code is as follows:

```
   ask turtles[if [pcolor] of patch-here = 6 [ set heading towards one-of neighbors4 in-cone 1 270 with [pcolor] = grey
```

However I get the error:
TOWARDS expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.

What should be done to the code to prevent this error? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting `nobody`, that means that there isn't always a patch meeting the conditions you have set up.

You need to decide what you want to do in that case. Suppose you decide the turtle should do nothing. Then the new code is:

```
ask turtles [
  if pcolor = 6 [
    let target one-of ...
    if is-patch? target [
      face target
    ]
  ]
]
```

Note that `of patch-here` is always redundant. A turtle always has direct access to the patch variables of the patch it is standing on.

Note also the use of `face`, which is more concise than `set heading towards`.